# Is there a useful measure of density of decidable sentences in PA?

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

Essential undecidability of PA says every complete extension of PA includes a non r.e. set of new "axioms," all undecidable in PA.  In that sense lots of sentences of PA are undecidable in PA.  And it is trivial to design a measure on, say sentences of PA with Godel number below $n$, where the set of decidable sentences has measure 1 (for all $n$ above the Godel number of the first decidable sentence, which would be 0=0 for the usual Godel numberings).  Just take the counting measure while restricting the count to decidable sentences.  Similar cheap tricks will give other uninformative results.

But is there a useful, nontrivial way to define the density of decidable sentences in PA?

The answer seems to be the state of the art.  It has nothing special to do with PA of course.  It holds for any incomplete theory, just using any theorem in place of $0=0$ and any refutable sentence in place of $0=1$. Chaitin's "heuristic principle" uses complexity to suggest that in fact almost all true sentences are independent in any recursive extension of PA, as cited in discussion of [How many of the true sentences are provable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4454/how-many-of-the-true-sentences-are-provable/7902#7902) But people do not seem persuaded by this.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4454/how-many-of-the-true-sentences-are-provable/7902#7902

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asymptotic density seems a very natural measure. The density of a set of sentences is the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the proportion of those sentences of length at most $n$ amongst all sentences of length at most $n$.

(One should use a formalism that has only finitely many sentences of a given length—for example, one can use variable symbols $x$, $x'$, $x''$, and so on, where the prime counts as another symbol, instead of indices; or else just stratify the sentences as a union of finite sets, such as by Gödel codes.)

Having density 1 means that as one considers longer and longer sentences, the proportion of them in the set goes to 100%. Having density 0 means that as one considers longer and longer sentences, the proportion of them in the set goes to 0.

We similarly get a notion of lower density and upper density by using $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Using this measure, it turns out that the set of theorems, the set of refutable sentences, and the set of independent sentences (over some fixed theory) all have a lower density bounded away from zero and an upper density bounded away from 1.

For example, every sentence of the form $\varphi\vee( 1=1)$ is a theorem, and this is a positive density set. Every sentence of the form $\varphi\wedge (1=0)$ is refutable, and this is a positive density set. And every sentence of the form $(\varphi\vee (1=1))\wedge\psi$ is independent, where $\psi$ is some fixed independent sentence, and this also is a positive density set.

Comment: (copy of [my Oct 2015 answer to the MSE question *Proportion of true statements that are provable*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494419/13130)) -- [Marek Zaionc](https://www.google.com/search?q="Marek+Zaionc"+asymptotic) has studied this issue for the last several years in the case of various systems of propositional logic. See also the StackExchange question [Are there more true statements than false ones?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625222/are-there-more-true-statements-than-false-ones).

Comment: But also, David's link goes back to 2009. It seems this question has been considered many times.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that sentences of the form $\varphi\vee( 1=1)$ are a positive density set.  How can I see that?

Comment: It is easier to see in the space of all strings of a specific length, not just wffs. For example, there are $26^n$ strings of length $n$ from an alphabet of size 26. If one fixes 6 of the characters to have specific values, there are $26^{n-6}$ strings in agreement, which makes proportion $1/26^6$, which is positive. In first-order logic, we don't allow all strings of characters as sentences, but the rate of growth is still basically exponential, and so fixing some characters to have specific values will still have about the corresponding fraction of the whole space.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes it is easy for the space of all strings of a specific length.  But being a disjunct of sentences with the length of $\varphi$ and of $(1=1)$ is a very special way to achieve the length of $\varphi\vee(1=1)$ so I do not see that the the rate of growth of the number of sentences is still basically exponential.

Comment: There are clear exponential lower bounds, by considering big conjunctions of atomic assertions. And there is an exponential upper bound, by the space of all sequences. So it is trapped between two exponentials with different bases.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I wonder if you have any thoughts about the idea I sketch near the end of my answer: Fix some $c>0$ and consider propositions in $n$ variables with $cn$ characters, where the name of a variable counts as just one character. So now the growth rate is like $n^{cn}$ instead of exponential, and the above argument doesn't apply.

Comment: I had thought that calculation occurs in propositional logic for SAT when as $n$ increases, we allow more variables. But in the first-order logic case of arithmetic, we aren't doing that. If one uses a fixed language, with variables $x,x',x'',x''',...$ that take increasing numbers of symbols to denote, as I mention in my answer, it seems clearly bounded by an exponential.

Comment: That way of considering SAT is useful in showing that almost every instance of SAT, with the right understanding of almost every, is easily solvable. It is like a version of my result on the halting problem, that for a certain model of Turing machine, we can solve almost every instance of the halting problem very quickly. Similar results hold for the knapsack problem and many other NP complete problems.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer By the way, since I am now at Notre Dame (although currently in NYC) I am much closer to you, perhaps we should meet up. I have vague plans to visit Ann Arbor, to visit with Andreas and Andrés at the very least.

Comment: Instead of using variables with increasing length, just use some stanard computer-sciency way of dealing with them. For example, we can ask that the free variables appearing in a formula always form an initial segment of $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$, and use de Bruijn indices for bound variables. (Each variable still contributes 1 to the size of the formula.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sure, that's fine, but not that different actually---in that scheme the higher variable instances cost more, since you can't ever use them in a "short" formula.

Comment: On your scheme not every subformula of a formula is a formula. Is that what we want?

Comment: I doubt it matters, but if it does, we can work around it easily, for instance all variables appearing in $\phi$ must be among $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ where $n$ is the seize of $\phi$. In any case, we're probably discussing irrelevant details, for if the whole topic is sensitive to them, then we're doing the wrong thing. I was just thinking that I'd prefer $x = x$ to always be small and of a fixed size.

Comment: I agree with that inclination, but the issue is that if there are infinitely many variables, you'd have infinitely many formulas of that size, and this prevents the asymptotic density from working. One needs to stratify the collection of all sentences by a tower of finite families. It  seems that there are many ways to do so, such as the methods we've been discussing.